Grouping records based on similarity
We have requirement to group all the similar records under one groupid for a given parent id.
I am sharing one simple example . I am trying to create sql query for this but no luck .
As you can see in below image we want group records in same group id which has child name similairty more than 80% ( for testing we can keep 50%).
As an output we need group id
Sharing sample data query .
I am fine we can find solution using query or python code . I am find with both
with test_data as (select 1 as child_id , 'TEST AS' as child , 'Test Inc.' as parent 
union 
select 2 as child_id , 'TEST ASIA PACIFIC SDN BHD' as child , 'Test Inc.' as parent 
union 
select 3 as child_id , 'TEST ASIA PTE LTD.' as child , 'Test Inc.' as parent 
union 
select 4 as child_id , 'TEST ASIA PTE LTD-SG' as child , 'Test Inc.' as parent 
union 
select 5 as child_id , 'TEST AUSTRALIA' as child , 'Test Inc.' as parent 
union 
select 6 as child_id , 'TEST AUSTRALIA PTY. LIMITED' as child , 'Test Inc.' as parent 
union 
select 7 as child_id , 'TEST AUSTRALIA PTY LTD' as child , 'Test Inc.' as parent 
union 
select 8 as child_id , 'TEST AUSTRALIA PTY LTD' as child , 'Test Inc.' as parent 
union 
select 9 as child_id , 'TEST-BR' as child , 'Test Inc.' as parent 
)
select * from test_data 


